# Laravel 5.5 class not found после установки дополнения

Tags: php, laravel, composer

Установил класс

```
composer require cedextech/trait-generator
```

По инструкции в `config/app.php` в массив providers добавил

```
 Cedextech\TraitGenerator\ServiceProvider::class
```

Ну и вроде всё работало. Но спустя время установил другой класс:

```
composer require intervention/image
```

и в конце установки composer выдал ошибку

> [Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError] Class
>   'Cedextech\TraitGenerator\ServiceProvider' not found

пробовал:
**composer dump-autoload** - не помогло,
**php artisan dump-autoload** выдает такую же ошибку
да и ***любая другая команда в composer выдает такую же ошибку***

Когда просто захожу на сайт тоже выдает

> FatalThrowableError in ProviderRepository.php line 146: Class
>   'Cedextech\TraitGenerator\ServiceProvider' not found

Что делать?? Это уже не первый раз, когда было раньше я просто не использовал установленное расширение (другое было), но проблема то осталась и нужно использовать расширения

Comment: `composer dumpautoload -o && composer clearcache` - попробуйте этот вариант.

Comment: А не пробовал просто проинспектировать исходники библиотеки? Может там действительно нет указанного класса? `intervention/image` у меня работает в нескольких проектах отлично без нареканий

Comment: @KostaB., вроде ваш вариант сработал, спасибо!

Comment: @МаксимК, конкретно с intervention/image проблем нет, это в целом была проблема

Answer (score 0):

Вот такая команда, дожна работать:

```
composer dumpautoload -o && composer clearcache
```

Comment: Вот так сработало, спасибо